# How can I use request.form in Flask/Python to get a variable textarea name?

Tags: python, html, flask

In my HTML template, I've added the following `<textarea>` into a flask for loop:

```
{% for message in messageList %}
    <form action="/comment/{{ message['id'] }}" method='POST' id='createComment{{ message["id"] }}'>
        <textarea name='comment{{ message["id"] }}' id='comment{{ message["id"] }}' class='postComment'></textarea>
        <button form='createComment{{ message["id"] }}' formaction="/comment/{{ message['id'] }}" formmethod='post' type='submit' class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget createCommentButton">Post a comment</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Using Flask with Python, I'm trying to grab the value of my dynamically generated `<textarea>`

(In the example above, if `id = 38`, name would read as `name="comment38"`)

I'm having trouble properly using request form to get this data, can anyone help?

Here's my Python code below which handles the route:

```
@app.route('/comment/<id>', methods=["POST"])
def createComment(id):
    query = 'INSERT INTO comments (message_id, user_id, comment, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (:message_id, :user_id, :comment, NOW(), NOW());'
    data = {
        'message_id' : id,
        'user_id' : session['loggedInUser'],
        'comment' : request.form["comment" & id]
    }
    mysql.query_db(query, data)
    flash('Comment has been created!')
    return redirect('/')
```

Does anyone know how I should appropriately format `request.form` in this scenario, as demonstrated above? Thank you!

Comment: The `id`s should also be unique on pages.

Comment: That's a great point as well that I've overlooked here and I'll update my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `request.form["comment" + id]`

Better yet, to avoid a key error:

`request.form.get("comment" + id, 'oops, bad id')`

Comment: this absolutely worked, and I thought I'd tried your method prior to posting here without solution, but as noted in my comments below, I was incorrect (although my snippet below also works). For some reason it seemed by my undesired results that `request.form` did not allow variables to be concatenated, but I was wrong and it absolutely works -- greatly appreciated sir!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new variable:

`form = request.form`

and setting my dictionary value to:

`'comment' : form["comment" + id]`

[*EDIT*] I had sworn I'd tried `request.form['comment' + id]` as the @GAEfan noted, but I wasn't able to get it to work (I must have had something else going on, as this absolutely is working now!) Answer accepted!